# How to Pass Values from Separate Classes to AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, viewcontroller

I have a class in my SignInViewController.swift:

```
class CredentialState: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = CredentialState()
    var signedIn = false
    var displayName: String?
    var photoUrl: NSURL?
}
```

I would like to use the variable signedIn to authenticate users in AppDelegate with an if-else statement. Currently, I have a way to set the viewcontroller to CustomTabBarController (custom programmatically made) **or** SignInViewController (storyboard made). The if statement would basically say if the value is false set the controller to the sign in screen and if it's true then go to the tab bar screen.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Main view controller is inside of customtabbarcontroller, which gives a tab overlay
//        window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()

    // Sets the main view to a storyboard element, such as SignInVC
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SignIn", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInVC") as! SignInViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood you correctly:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    // check login state
    if CredentialState.sharedInstance.signedIn {
        // Main view controller is inside of customtabbarcontroller, which gives a tab overlay
        window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()
    } else {
        // Sets the main view to a storyboard element, such as SignInVC
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SignIn", bundle: nil)
        let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInVC") as! SignInViewController
        window?.rootViewController = loginVC
    }

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure of what you are asking, yet I'll try to answer that. Basically what you need to do is just simply have this piece of code above your CredentialState class:

```
credentialState : CredentialState = CredentialState()
```

In this way you can change or check your signedIn variable from AppDelegate. So simply in the AppDelegate file you can:

```
if(credentialState.signedIn == true) ...
```

Hope I was able to answer your question